# vis.js resetting chart zoom to the original loading

Tags: vis.js

How can I reset the vis.js timeline/Graph2D scatter chart zoom to the state it was originally loaded as I would have zoomed into just deep enough to be able to easily come back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On initial load, the Timeline and Graph2d fit the displayed contents, unless you specified a custom start and end for the window. There is a method `fit()` to fit the contents again.